# That we know of yet

Tags: relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses, that, independent-clauses

The movie 'Lady Bird' has this [conversation](https://youtu.be/cNi_HC839Wo?t=2m16s):
(Please click on it and listen to the clip starting at 2:16)

> **Christine McPherson:** *What I'd really like is to be on Math Olympiad.*
>
> **Teacher:** *But math isn't something you’re terribly strong in.*
>
> **Christine McPherson:** *That we know of yet.*

What exactly does the last line mean?

Also, I'd like the answer to determine its syntax, i.e., whether the last line's added by Christine to the teacher's line as a subordinate clause or it's a separate, independent sentence.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "…strong at"? I think the mother superior actually says "at".

Comment: You literally don't understand what * That we know of yet* means, or you don't understand its grammar?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I hear 'in' and the script says it's 'in'.  Regarding whether or not I know what it means, I get the idea. But in order to get the exact meaning, I need to know its syntax, and knowing the syntax will help me better understand the line.

Comment: It's perfectly idiomatic casual US English.  Whether you consider the last line to be subordinate or not depends on what school you attended.

Comment: Consider that there are two different speakers, and Christine is completing the teacher's sentence.  Otherwise the two bits would be treated as one sentence.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is "in" its barely audible, but I listened again more carefully, and "in" is probably the preposition uttered.

Comment: It should be noted that "in" and "at" are about equally idiomatic in this context.

Comment: @HotLicks So, you think it's a subordinate clause. Then, what kind of subordinate clause is it? Since the object of 'of' is missing, I think it should be a relative clause. If so, what's the antecedent? "something you’re terribly strong in"?

Comment: @JK2 - "Know of" is an idiom with the same meaning as "know about".

Comment: @HotLicks Do you mean "know of" doesn't require an object?

Comment: Christine is asking a a rhetorical question and then giving an answer to it: 'That we know of? Yet.' This undermines the Teachers view of  Christine, not being strong with mathematics, and given the opportunity of entering the Math Olympiad, Christine could prove the teacher otherwise. The 'Yet' answer shows defiance and determination that she will enter the competition.

Answer (score 1):

"That we know of yet" is a formulaic response, a trope used to express a kind of hope or alarm for a future situation. It is seen in constructions that are meant to cast doubt or counter expectations about an outcome, either positive or negative. Examples:

> **A:** There are no termites in the house we're buying.
>   **B:** That we know of yet. We'll need an inspection to make certain.

This suggests that there may be termites. B is cautioning A against overconfidence, perhaps in case they thought to save money on a termite inspection.

> **A:** There just aren't any women in the world who are interested in a man like me.
>   **B:** That we know of yet. You might find your true love tomorrow. You never know.

Here B is trying to boost A's confidence and spread a little optimism.

I confess that when I read your example it sounded a little off to me, because the usual formula seen in my examples was not strictly observed. The statement "But math isn't something you're terribly strong in" would perhaps be better answered by a statement like "Not yet" or "I'm working on it." But when I saw the clip, it seemed perfectly natural given the character of the girl. With that single sentence, a trope slightly misused, she demonstrates that she is rough around the edges, perhaps poor at math, but resolved to use all the strength she has to rectify the situation in order to get what she wants, possibly in defiance of everyone's expectations of her. It is this slightly off-key usage that paints an emotional picture of a charmingly overmatched but determined girl that the audience will relate to.

This is the sort of contextual usage you can't really learn unless you are very deeply immersed in a language, enough so to pick up the invisible radio waves of cultural connotation. And even if you're a native speaker, you may be falling prey to the notion that language has to make a kind of mathematical sense all the time.

Language is not perfect. But it does continually amaze with all the things it can convey on top of its literal denotations.

Comment: So do you think it's a subordinate clause or an independent sentence?

Comment: It's using ellipsis to have the clause serve for the whole sentence: "[There are none] that we know of yet." Such elisions are a common feature of English speech. The part that is readily understood is deleted to make a shorter statement.

Comment: Thanks. So she's saying "[math isn't something you’re terribly strong in] that we know of yet". Here, is "that we know of yet" a relative clause having "something you're terribly strong in" as its antecedent?

Comment: That's right, JK2.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Could you please incorporate in your answer the syntactic analysis that it's a relative clause? Also, is it possible to leave out 'that' in Christine's line? (Normally, 'that' leading this type of relative clause is omissible.) What if she said the entire sentence herself: _Math isn't something I'm strong in that we know of yet._ Is 'that' here omissible?

Answer (score 0):

In most languages, one can add to a previous sentence by extending it:

Teacher: But math isn't something you’re terribly strong in.

Christine McPherson: That we know of yet.

There is an implied non-essential subordinate clause at the end, which is common in speech and which in our example is given by the second speaker: But math isn't something you’re terribly strong in, that we know of yet.

I am giving the reference only to indicate that nonessential elements can exist and here, it happens to be a non-essential subordinate clause for purposes of discourse logic. This is a common conversational "strategy" or tool. Well, it just exists. Perhaps someone else can define it better than I have.

[nonessential elements at the end of sentences](http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/punctuation/mastering-the-art-of-comma-usage/commas-nonessential-elements/)